# Why drop overlay scrollbars in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar

Why has Ubuntu 15.10 dropped overlay scroll-bars? Are there any specific advantages of dropping it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because Gnome has implemented theire own overlay scrollbars.
Unity is based on gnome so, for avoiding to maintains two overlay scrollbar, they drops the ubuntu's overlay scrollbar for using gnome's overlay scrollbar